# Webscraping with python selenium, succeed to login one time, next try it fails

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing my first python script ever...with some googling and watching tutorials on youtube i managed to write some code to scrape my groceries from an online supermarket. At least, that is what I am trying.

Now I have a problem which i am not able to solve. Sometimes my scripts works like expexted and performs all the steps that i have put in my script. But most of the times it failes. It fails at the point I have entered my username + password (there are correct). The site gives the message that username and password are not valid.

Here is the code I have so far. Is there anybody who can help me with a solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,

Simon Kruizinga

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#website url
url = 'https://www.jumbo.com/'
driver.get(url)

#Reject cookies
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))
    )
    element.click()
#Navigate to usermenu
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "jum_user_menu_large_button"))
    )
    element.click()
 #Navigate to loginbutton  
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Inloggen"))
    )
    element.click() 
    
except:
    print("failed to go to loginpage")

#username + password

    
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "username"))
    )
    element.clear()
    search = driver.find_element_by_id ("username")
    search.send_keys("my@email.com")
 
except:
    print ("Failed to enter username")
    
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "password"))
    )
    element.clear()
    search = driver.find_element_by_id ("password")
    search.send_keys("MyS3cr3tPasswOrd!")
    
except:
    print ("Failed to enter password")

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "submit"))
    )
    time.sleep(3)
    element.click()
   
except:
    print("failed to login into jumbo.com")

#Navigate to order historie   
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "jum_user_menu_large_button"))
    )
    element.click()
    
except:
    print("failed to go to dropdown menu")
   
    
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="homepage-jum-v2"]/div[3]/header/div[3]/div/header/div[2]/nav/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a'))
    )
    element.click()
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ui-selectmenu-status"))
    )
    element.click()
        
except:
    print("failed to go to bestellingen menu")
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimize the above code with variable names, single - double quotes issues, multiple Webdriverwait object creation issue resolved and element_to_be_clickable where ever is required.

**Code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.jumbo.com/")
try:
    reject_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler")))
    reject_element.click()
    # Navigate to usermenu
    jumbo_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "jum_user_menu_large_button")))
    jumbo_element.click()
    # Navigate to loginbutton
    Inlog_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Inloggen")))
    Inlog_element.click()
except:
    print("failed to go to loginpage")

# username + password

try:
    user_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "username")))
    user_element.clear()
    user_element.send_keys("my@email.com")
except:
    print("Failed to enter username")

try:
    password_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "password")))
    password_element.clear()
    password_element.send_keys("MyS3cr3tPasswOrd!")

except:
    print("Failed to enter password")

try:
    submit_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submit")))
    sleep(3)
    submit_element.click()

except:
    print("failed to login into jumbo.com")

# Navigate to order historie
try:
    historie_order_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "jum_user_menu_large_button")))
    historie_order_element.click()

except:
    print("failed to go to dropdown menu")

try:
    new_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='homepage-jum-v2']/div[3]/header/div[3]/div/header/div[2]/nav/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a")))
    new_element.click()
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ui-selectmenu-status")))
    element.click()
except:
    print("failed to go to bestellingen menu")
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! Unfortunatly it didn't solve the issue. I have noticed that I can login by clicking "submit"serveral times. There is no particual number of times I have to click submit. Once submitting is succeded my python script is running like it is suposed to. Ofcourse I can try to write a script that keeps hitting submit until logging in succeeds but that is not the right solution i guess...

Comment: @Simon : Sadly I don't have right creds to test this out.

Comment: You can try it out with Js integration as well `driver.execute_script("elements[0].click();", submit_button)` write this line after sleep(3)